# Get numbers from string and set them in array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string like this `100 and 20000` and I need to extract the numbers with regex and push them to array and access them by indices. Can you give me a little push here, my knowledge on regex are very limited. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `\d+` to match numbers and `match` to get the result in array.
Use `g` global flag to match all the numbers.

```js
var str = '100 and 20000';

var numbers = str.match(/\d+/g);


console.log(numbers); // numbers is an array: ["100", "20000"]
alert(numbers);
```